Icon Not Appearing in JFrame (VSCode)
I am working on some fx with java for the first time, and I'm using Maven in VSCode. I figured out how to get text to appear in a frame using a label, but I can't get an image to appear, and I don't know why.
My expected outcome is for the image "crown.jpg" as well as the text "Hi Adam!" to appear in the frame. However, only the text appears.
Here is my code:
package firstfxjava;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // JFrame = a GUI window to add components to

        // JLabel = a GUI display area for a string of text, an image, or both

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("crown.jpg"); //creates an ImageIcon

        JLabel label = new JLabel(); // creates a lable
        label.setText("Hi Adam!"); //sets text of lable
        label.setIcon(image);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates a frame
        frame.setTitle("JFrame title goes here"); //sets title of frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of application frame
        frame.setSize(420,420); //sets the x-dimension, and y-dimension of frame
        frame.setVisible(true); //make frame visible
        frame.add(label);
    }
}

Here is my files if that is helpful: (https://i.sstatic.net/QSxpF5yn.png)

You're trying to get the image as a file and using the wrong relative path to the image since you're not taking the user's directory into account. Better still to get the image as a resource though.

Also, only make the JFrame visible after adding all components to it.

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels So, how would i fix this? Sorry, I'm new to the technical stuff, but should i move the image to the resources folder?

ImageIcon() doesn't throw an exception on an error, it just remains uninitialized, so I expect the filename you give it isn't correct (missing directory path or something).

Please read the answer in the duplicate. Then use .getResource() on the class object to get a URL and call ImageIO.Read(URL) to get the image.
